# Problems with installation Hadoop on Mac OS

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install hadoop on Mac os using this [instruction](https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/547/install-hadoop-330-on-mac#google_vignette). At this step `sbin/start-dfs.sh`, I have a problem.
My result:
`Starting namenodes on [localhost] Starting datanodes localhost: datanode is running as process 26210.  Stop it first. Starting secondary namenodes [https://account.jetbrains.com:443] sed: 1: "s/^/https://account.jet ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'`.

What can be done about it? I really hope for your help!

hadoop-env:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Generated SSH key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost 
::1             localhost 
0.0.0.0 https://account.jetbrains.com:443  
1.2.3.4 account.jetbrains.com  
1.2.3.4 http://www.jetbrains.com  
1.2.3.4 www-weighted.jetbrains.com  
0.0.0.0 account.jetbrains.com
```

Maybe there is some error in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Why is your hostname set to an HTTPS address?

Comment: I don't know. I followed the instructions

Comment: The instructions work fine, although you should follow the official Apache Hadoop documentation, not random blogs. Your machine itself is configured incorrectly. For example, show us any environment variables you've set in `hadoop-env.sh`, or any changes you've made to `/etc/hosts` and `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` outside of Hadoop... Besides that, Docker or a VM work fine and provide ways for us to reproduce any problems with your installation

Comment: @OneCricketeer hadoop-env: `#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`  
$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`  
/etc/hosts: 
`127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
0.0.0.0 https://account.jetbrains.com:443 
1.2.3.4 account.jetbrains.com 
1.2.3.4 http://www.jetbrains.com 
1.2.3.4 www-weighted.jetbrains.com 
0.0.0.0 account.jetbrains.com `  Maybe there is some error in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Yes, remove all lines/values with `jetbrains` in it

Comment: Also, Hadoop doesn't support Java above version 8 or maybe 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Hadoop assumes that `0.0.0.0` will map to a local connection.

You appear to have tried to bypass JetBrains account checks by modifying your hosts file. Please revert your hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But now, I have problem with ssh localhost : `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. Help me please, how can I fix this?